# Dependency property is not working by some UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I made PageTransition UserControl for page transition effect, However it is not working. I don't know, why is it not working.

I have a experience in made by DependencyProperty, It is a right working. But, My new code is not working in this time.

PageTransition.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentViewProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CurrentView),
               typeof(UserControl),
               typeof(PageTransition));
        public UserControl CurrentView
        {
            get => (UserControl)GetValue(CurrentViewProperty);
            set
            {
                if(value is UserControl newControl)
                {
                    Pages.Push(newControl);
                    if (CurrentView != default)
                    {
                        CurrentView.Loaded -= NewPageLoaded;
                        UnloadOldPage();
                    }
                    else
                        ShowNextPage();
                }
            }
        }
```

PageTransition.cs.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=_this}" x:Name="contentControl">
</ContentControl>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
private UserControl currentPage = new MainPage() { DataContext = new MainPageViewModel() };
public UserControl CurrentPage
{
    get => currentPage;
    set
    {
        this.currentPage = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentPage)));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs.xaml

```
    <userControls:PageTransition 
        CurrentView="{Binding CurrentPage, ElementName=_this, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        TransitionType="SlideAndFade"/>
```

I am using the PageTransition UserControl in MainWindow. When I change the CurrentPage value in MainWindow, CurrentView value not changed in PageTransition UserControl

Comment: Your dependency property declaration is wrong. There must only be `SetValue(CurrentViewProperty, value)` in the property setter, nothing else. The code you have there currently should be moved to a PropertyChangedCallback, that is registered by PropertyMetadata passed to the Register method.

Comment: I've rolled back you last edit. Your assumption that your question hasn't got to do with property metadata is wrong. As said, you have to register a PropertyChangedCallback.